# Pseudomonoids versus monoidal pseudofunctors from $\Delta$

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, monoidal-categories

I have been trying to find some literature (if there is any) on the relationship between pseudomonoids and monoidal pseudofunctors from the monoidal theory of a monoid, $\Delta$ (I am interested in this for more general monoidal theories). I haven't tracked through all of the coherence diagrams, but I would expect the pseudofunctors to pseudomonoids direction to be relatively straightforward (although I could certainly be wrong!), whereas the reverse direction seems as though it would require a bit more nuance.